# Как загружать файлы многопоточно?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

У меня есть определенное количество файлов, которые нужно загрузить на устройство. Все что нужно для загрузки из сети есть (Имею адрес файла). Все бы ничего, но этих файлов у меня довольно много. Как я понял мою задачу нужно реализовывать с помощью пула потоков, но так как я очень мало работал с загрузкой файлов и потоками, то мне пока непонятно как это реализовать. Может у кого-то была схожая задача как у меня, может кто сможет скинуть годных статей с примерами кода по этой теме?
Спасибо за понимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все несколько проще. Если у Вас уже есть метод синхронной загрузки файла (в каком потоке запустили загрузку, в том и загружается), то достаточно создать коллекцию из `Callable<T>`, где в реализации происходит синхронная загрузка файла, и кинуть ее в метод `ExecutorService.invokeAll()`. `ExecutorService` выбирайте на свое усмотрение, но для большинства задач подойдет `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`.

Comment: Сяп) Все оказалось легче, чем я думал)